# Trying to install Ruby 1.9.3-p547 exits with WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir, --with-readline-dir

Tags: ruby, gcc, osx-mavericks, rbenv

I've been trying to install Ruby 1.9.3-p547 for the past 2 days on OS X 10.9.3 with rbenv:

```
CC="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3/bin/gcc" rbenv install 1.9.3-p547
```

but it keeps reporting an error:

```
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p547...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977
Results logged to /var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977.log

Last 10 log lines:
x ruby-1.9.3-p547/golf_prelude.c
/var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977/ruby-1.9.3-p547 /var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977  ~/code/dpplus
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir, --with-readline-dir
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-    build.20140528111136.82977/ruby-1.9.3-p547':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977
Results logged to /var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977/ruby-1.9.3-p547 /var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-build.20140528111136.82977 ~/code/dpplus
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir, --with-readline-dir
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/6t/33jmvscd6vg_tlqk40c4vsg80000gp/T/ruby-    build.20140528111136.82977/ruby-1.9.3-p547':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've been trying with gcc 4.8.3, gcc 4.6, readline and libyaml (all from Homebrew). It works with apple-gcc42 (from Homebrew as well), but this gives a problem with the Spring-gem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I was missing Xcode command line tools. I've installed it with the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This was one of the posts that helped me: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/440#issuecomment-27803534

Comment: After installing Yosemite, I had to run the command above to fix install of Ruby 1.9.3. Ruby 2.1.3 installed without issue without the command-line tools.

Comment: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`